# Securing authenticated traffic on Azure website without custom certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, shared, azure-web-app-service

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC website to be hosted as a shared Azure website with custom domain name.

For the backend portion of the site (for specific users only) I need a login form and from that point on all traffic should be SSL encrypted. However I don't have a custom certificate and would like to avoid that extra cost.

I noticed that free websites already serve over HTTPS with a wildcard certificate for *.azurewbesites.net. Is that "free" azurewebsites.net-address also available for shared websites with custom domain(s) so I can simply redirect all "pages" that require authentication via the https://xyz.azurewebsites.net address? I'm aware that would be a cross-domain redirect which is visible to the end-user but that is not an issue since it's only a select group of users...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the *.azurewebsites.net domain is your only option to have HTTPS without extra cost. The domain is always available, even if you use a custom domain, because it's used for a few additional services (like your repo, remote console, ...).

Comment: While this is possible, it's not recommended for securing sensitive information since the certificate is used for other generic web sites. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/12/13/securing-your-windows-azure-web-sites-waws-with-https-and-ssl.aspx